# Check class in HTML via jQuery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
   <div class="col-16-6">      
          <div class="product-image">
            <img src="//image.com/{{ImagePath}}" />
          </div>
    </div>
```

I want if my HTML structure has `.product-image` class, alert this.

My JS:

```
 maxWidth: function () {
        if ($('.product-detail-lightbox').find('.product-image').length) {
            alert("image ok");
        } else {
            alert("image none");
        }
    },
```

But its not working. Checked devtools but not any error.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your `.product-detail-lightbox` element HTML.

Comment: check here: http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/157/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.product-detail-lightbox').find('.product-image')` will find elements with "product-image" class those are child elements of element with class "product-detail-lightbox".  Your html template doesn't have element with class "product-detail-lightbox". Thus you will never get alert as "image ok". You can wrap your .product-image element in another div element like below.

```
<div class="col-16-6">      
    <div class="product-detail-lightbox">
        <div class="product-image">
            <img src="//image.com/{{ImagePath}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your JS as below.

```
maxWidth: function () {
    if ($('.product-detail-lightbox').find('.product-image').length) {
        alert("image ok");
    } else {
        alert("image none");
    }
},
```

Here is fiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/mrk_m/g60sesrd/3/

Comment: Thank you but every result is "image ok"

Comment: Please check it. When I remove .product-image class, same result: "image ok"

Comment: Can you check once again. My bad. I wrapped it in class product-detail-box instead of product-detail-lightbox. fiddle also is updated now. you can uncomment html div in it and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several elements with the "product-detail-lightbox" class, then the $('.product-detail-lightbox') is returning an array of objects; that's why it's not working.

To let this work, you need to loop through this array and test each object if it contains the needed element :

```
function maxWidth () {
        $('.product-detail-lightbox').each(function(){
            if ($(this).find('.product-image').length) {
                alert("image ok");
            } else {
                alert("image none");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: <div class="product-detail-lightbox"><div class="product-image">
<img src="" /></div></div>
<div class="product-detail-lightbox"><div class="product-image">
<img src="" /></div></div>
 function maxWidth () {
  $('.product-detail-lightbox').each(function(){
   if ($(this).find('.product-image').length) {
    alert("image ok");
   } else {
    alert("image none");
   }
  });
 }        this isn't working ?!

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/g60sesrd/2/) may answer your problem.

```
$(document).find('div.product-image').length
```